# Wi-Fi radio without an antenna

Tags: radio, wifi

I'm mostly unfamiliar with radio, but I've read that you will eventually fry a transmitter if you operate it without some kind of antenna or at least a dummy load attached to it.

The question is specifically about consumer Wi-Fi hardware with detachable antennas (such as desktop PCs that have the screw-on SMA(?)(RP-SMA?) antenna connector, or access points like a PicoStation that use the same kind of screw-on antenna).

1. *Will* you fry the Wi-Fi radio if it's kept turned on without the antenna attached to the connector, or is it less of an issue for consumer Wi-Fi, compared to the more powerful radio transmitters?
2. Is it still an issue if the radio is *technically* powered on but isn't actively connected to a Wi-Fi network, merely doing an occasional scan (i.e. transmitting a few frames every now and then) but sitting unused otherwise?
3. Can the opposite be an issue, i.e. can being connected to a [too big antenna](https://www.wimo.com/en/18686-24) damage the transmitter? I assume it can damage the receiver at least.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm mostly unfamiliar with radio, but I've read that you will eventually fry a transmitter if you operate it without some kind of antenna or at least a dummy load attached to it.

If the transmitter's output amplifier is not designed to be safe in that case. Consumer devices' amplifiers tend to be.

> Will you fry the Wi-Fi radio if it's kept turned on without the antenna attached to the connector, or is it less of an issue for consumer Wi-Fi, compared to the more powerful radio transmitters?

Can't tell you. That is down to the specific chipset, and the specific design of the board it sits on. It's unlikely that a Wifi chipset is not designed to automatically detect this situation and be safe, or that its output amplifier isn't designed to withstand the reflections of its own signal, but: there's no general statement that would be possible to make.

Same goes for your other two questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you key a transmitter on without an antenna, some will get damaged, some will survive. The difference is how they have been designed.

In the situation where there is a large market, of uneducated users, for instance WiFi, where there is every likelihood of someone, somewhere, operating their WiFi with the external antenna disconnected, having a transmitter that breaks in those circumstances would be very bad for business. The brand would get a bad name, become known as 'fragile', all the reviews would tell people to avoid.

Generally, the lower the power of the transmitter, the easier it is to design it to deal with the power reflected from an absent antenna.